# open_id_authentication on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, openid

I'm migrating an application from Rails 2 to Rails 3.
The application uses Open ID to log in to Google, and I'm using `open_id_authentication` plugin.

The code looks something like this:

```
options = {
  :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id',
  :required => [ 'http://axschema.org/contact/email', 
                 'http://axschema.org/namePerson/first',
                 'http://axschema.org/namePerson/last' ], 
  :oauth => { 
     :consumer =>  OAUTH_CONSUMER_TOKEN,
     :scope => "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" 
  } 
} 
authenticate_with_open_id('https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id',  options)
   do |result, identity_url, registration, extended_attributes|

   email = registration["http://axschema.org/contact/email"]

end
```

This was working properly on Rails 2, but when I updated to Rails 3, and updated the Open ID plugin (for compatibility reasons), when I try to get the email attribute I get the following error:

**ArgumentError in SessionsController#create**
     http://schema.openid.net/contact/email is not a defined simple registration field

```
ruby-openid (2.1.8) lib/openid/extensions/sreg.rb:32:in `check_sreg_field_name'
ruby-openid (2.1.8) lib/openid/extensions/sreg.rb:266:in `[]'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:33:in `open_id_authentication'
vendor/plugins/open_id_authentication/lib/open_id_authentication.rb:114:in `complete_open_id_authentication'
vendor/plugins/open_id_authentication/lib/open_id_authentication.rb:90:in `authenticate_with_open_id'
```

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it? I know the communication is working properly, since I get Google's page and get asked for my password, but I can't figure out why the email attribute stopped coming through when updating to Rails 3.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956522/retrieve-openid-ax-attributes-from-google-yahoo-in-rails/1960389#1960389) - this question seems like a duplicate question of that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby open_id_authentication with Google OpenID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492043/ruby-open-id-authentication-with-google-openid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://toddsedano.blogspot.com/2010/05/integrating-openid-google-apps-and-ruby.html). The code on how to fetch the email AX attribute is below:

```
options = {
  :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id',
  :required => [ 'http://axschema.org/contact/email', 
                 'http://axschema.org/namePerson/first',
                 'http://axschema.org/namePerson/last' ], 
  :oauth => { 
     :consumer =>  OAUTH_CONSUMER_TOKEN,
     :scope => "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" 
  } 
} 
authenticate_with_open_id('https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id',  options)
   do |result, identity_url, registration, extended_attributes|

   ax_response = OpenID::AX::FetchResponse.from_success_response(request.env[Rack::OpenID::RESPONSE])

   email = ax_response['http://axschema.org/contact/email'].first

end
```